# Difference between <className>.class and this(representing the <classname>)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have `class` like `Test`.I am passing `class` as argument.

What is the difference between the below code :

```
    Map maps = new HashMap();
    maps.put("ARG_ID",Test.class);
```

and

```
     Map maps = new HashMap();
     maps.put("ARG_ID",this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test.class` is the `Class` object representing `Test`, it is used for reflection and generics. `this`, when referenced in a class, is the current instance of the class you are working on.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the first form passes a reference to an instance of `Class`. The second form passes the `this` reference - which is an *instance* of a class... they're two entirely different objects.

If you used generics to describe what your key/value types should be, it would make it a lot clearer what you're trying to do, and the compiler would stop you from trying to add the wrong kind of value.